# Is it possible to edit CSS rules that don't apply to anything yet in Firebug?

Tags: css, firebug, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm helping improve a Wordpress site with a responsive design. Currently, I have media queries set up for the different screen sizes, but there are no CSS rules in them right now.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles go here */
}
```

Is there a way to edit and add brand new rules into the media queries live on Firebug? It would be more convenient than adding a "dummy" CSS rule, putting it on the FTP, then testing it in the browser and editing from there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, no you cannot make edits in firebug that will affect your site permanently. You can alter the code to see what it does and then copy and paste it into a separate script. As for your answer though, you'll ultimately have to write a separate css script for it.

That would be nice if you could (maybe an upgrade), but it would probably require some sort of password for security purposes so not just anyone could edit it.

Comment: I'm not looking to edit something on Firebug and have it permanently affect the site. What I would like to be able to do is add to the empty media queries when I examine them in Firebug. I hope I am explaining this correctly.

Comment: Then yes you can do that. All you need to do it click on source edits and you can manipulate your code/queries

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just click on the CSS tab and then Source Edits. Then copy over your changes to your actual CSS if it's what you want. Just keep in mind though that you are defining your media queries with `min-device-width`, so on a desktop this will not render any changes because the device width doesn't change if you resize the browser.

Likewise, you can also use the Chrome's Debugger Tool - I find this a lot more helpful. You can make changes to the CSS on the "Elements" tab. Then click on the "Resources" tab find your Styles folder - Chrome will actually tell you which CSS files you've edited and also have them versioned for you. Simply right-click and save the version of CSS file that matches the edits you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the     min-device-width doesn't change! I had not realized that.

Comment: no worries, there's a neat extension in chrome that lets you resize your browser according to different devices (which you can probably use to test your media queries): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon I've read some good reviews about it, maybe it may help you